# Error when Hiding toolbar with AppCompat-v7

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I have tried to hide toolbar from the text change listener

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    toolbar.animate()
        .translationY(-toolbar.getBottom())
        .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
        .start();
}
```

this solution works perfectly on higher level api(successfully work on kitkat).But I got following error on running device with api level 10.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.animate

the layout xml portion is

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ff6d7fe2"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I have not set the toolbar as support action bar.why I got this error even if using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you are using [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) method `toolbar.animate()`. And this is only compatible with API level above 12. So you can use JakeWharton's [NineOldAndroid](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids) library to make it compatible with APIs lower than 12.

Comment: my project already contain nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar for sliding drawer.Is the same lib taking effect on above situation?

Comment: Check imports in your class. Is it from the nineoldandroid or is from android's

Comment: Make sure you are using the toolbar.animate() from the library, not native

Answer (score 1):

`Toolbar` is just a view, and `animate` is a method on `View` introduced after v10 - therefore it doesn't exist and crashes when you try to invoke it on a v10 device.

You can use

```
ViewCompat.animate(toolbar).translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

But this will not do any animation pre ICS. You can use NineOldAndroid as Sajal suggests, drop the animation on older devices, or animate the view using the old animation framework.